# tutorial ROSberryPi Setting up Hydro on RaspberryPi failing on rosconsole

Tags: ros, turtlebot, raspberrypi, rasbperrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Im installing turtlebot software on raspberry pi using this turtorial

ROSberryPiSetting up Hydro on RaspberryPi

but im stuck in the build part of turtlebot it wants this requirement ros console-bridge but when i get to that section of the tutorial i'm missing something console_bridge

1.1.1
this command returns this

sed -e "s/rosconsole/console_bridge" rosconsole/package.xml > console_bridge/package.xml
**sed: -e expression #1, char 27: unterminated `s' command**

Any help would be
appreciated thanks chocjulio

PS thanks for the tutorial it really helped get me going you should do one for turlebot

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/110146/tutorial-rosberrypi-setting-up-hydro-on-raspberrypi-failing-on-rosconsole/) by [chocjulio33](https://answers.ros.org/users/9626/chocjulio33/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2013-12-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tim Sweet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5998/tim-sweet/) on 2013-12-18**:
Just a note: I've updated the Wiki to fix this problem. the correct sed command should have been "sed -e "s/rosconsole/console_bridge/" rosconsole/package.xml > console_bridge/package.xml" (notice the terminating slash after console_bridge)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured this out, sed is a find and replace utility i did it manually. still no turtlebot on pi yet. This makes me thinks somethings changed. Also just a place holder im currently compiling pcl and flann manually on the pi flann took 27hrs to compile but installed ok! Great success! Now i'm waiting on PCL to complete its been going 40+ hrs.

Trying to learn how to cross compile but that is definitly harder but will greatly reduce compile times andd im going to either try to release an image or convert compiled code to a deb! Has anyone made a turtlebot out of a pi?

Chocjulio

---

Originally posted by [chocjulio33](https://answers.ros.org/users/9626/chocjulio33/) with karma: 26 on 2013-12-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) on 2013-12-16**:
You might want to check out Embedded Sig. They had some discussions regarding Rasberry Pi stuff.

http://wiki.ros.org/sig/Embedded

**Comment by [autonomy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3784/autonomy/) on 2013-12-18**:
May I suggest creating a virtual machine with the Raspbian environment and building in there? That would save you some time, even with setting up the VM - try http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/344/emulation-on-a-windows-pc or http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=37386